# How do I keep semicolons in csv file when exporting to excel?

Tags: excel

I have a csv file that looks like:

```
    "","Var1","Var2","Freq"
    "1","","Cardiovascular_Dx","0:23313  "
    "2","","Cardiovascular_Dx","1: 3315  "
```

When I export this to Excel I get this:

```
        Var2    Freq
   0    Cardiovascular_Dx   0:23313  
   1    Cardiovascular_Dx   2.34375
```

ie: the 1:3315 gets transformed to 2.34375. Is there a way around this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

you must delete the space after

```
"1:
```

Regards.